# Is there a way to check integrity of earthing provisions?

Tags: power, safety, wiring, grounding

We have a complex network of earth wires and earth pits. These earth wires are connected to power panels and CNC machines. However, the earthing system is very old and poorly maintained.

**Is there a way to check if the panel/ machine is properly earthed or not?**

Obviously, visual inspection and line tracing is an option to trace the connectivity of earth wire, but I am looking for a more efficient solution.

For example - **Is there any specific method to test if the body of earthed machine/ panel is at earth potential and will remain as such?**

Comment: An earth impedance/integrity tester springs to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the USA this is called a [Ground Bond Test](https://www.google.com/search?q=ground+bond+test). There is specialized equipment that sends a high current through the grounding/bonding conductors, measures the resultant voltage, then calculates the resistance to ground.

In a well-grounded system, this voltage will be very low.  If the voltage exceeds a certain threshold (meaning that the resistance to ground is too high) the test is automatically halted.

In your case, you would first find (or create) a known-good earthing point.  Then you would perform the ground-bond test from this point to the ground connections of individual machines/panels.

Ground-bond testing equipment is expensive; you may wish to find a testing agency that can rent it to you, or which will perform the tests for you.

Comment: Hiring the test equipment is almost impossible (at least in my country) because the license is binded with calibration certificate and the operator course/exam. So nobody is so stupid to rent an instrument and to loose the money for inspection.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: Interesting!  Around here it is pretty standard, at least in my experience.  [ElectroRent](https://www.electrorent.com/us/home), for example, sells new equipment for a few thousand USD or rents it for a few hundred USD per month.  (This isn't a recommendation; I haven't done business with them).  It's true that you can't certify your results if you do it yourself, but this may not matter to the OP.

Comment: They have really nice gadgets. A DIY inspection is always welcome.

Comment: Isn't there anything that I can do in house? Using meggers etc?

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay Well, a megger is opposite of what you need. It provides a high voltage into a (nominally) open circuit.  You need something that can drive a high current into a (nominal) short circuit.  If you have an appropriate power supply you could create a bunch of current and measure the resultant voltage separately. But most power supplies can't feed a short circuit.  They either limit themselves or simply fail :) Also, the measured voltage should be in the mV range, so it's tricky...

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay Also, in case of bad ground, you would be presenting a sustained voltage on the ground lines... This is bad, as you can imagine.  A dedicated ground bond tester limits the voltage automatically if it needs to.

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay And a reason to not simply use an Ohmmeter to check for resistance is because they only source a few mA.  An iffy ground connection could sink a few mA successfully and still be dangerous in the case of higher amperage fault.

Comment: Your answer is a good one and Its one of the solutions. But isn't there no way I can check it myself without any extra equipment? Please see my latest edit.

Comment: Sorry, @SagarUpadhyay, but this is the only good way I can think of. You could, of course, run all new grounding wires to the utility ground, and hope that it's sufficient. But even then, you'd probably want to perform a ground-bond test on the new connections. Perhaps someone else here will post a better idea!